How to use stream with a source view in DBT
Currently, I have a DBT project for Snowflake which uses streams, views, tasks and procedures, every time the project runs my views are re-created and the streams that use those views stop working, this is normal functionality of Snowflake stream, is there a way to perform the action CREATE IF NOT EXISTS VIEW in dbt data model?
I read the documentation and I understand the different types of materialization

You can write a custom materialization that checks for the existence of a view before creating. I found this through a quick search (I have not used/reviewed this code, but it should give you a place to start): https://gist.github.com/tpilewicz/b3db64c35ec69396dafedf70749b3709
